# Storing matcha tea in a thermos?

Tags: tea

lately i started to drink matcha tea, as an experiment instead of coffee, and i have read many descriptions about it.

I want to drink matcha tea to work, but i dont want to make it every time here,but instead to have it in a thermos.I have an 1L stainless still thermos and the quantity is quite enough for 3~4 cups of tea.

So, is it ok to make the tea in the morning and having it till the end of working day or this process is not good for the tea?
Will it change the color of it also?

Regards

Comment: Hello LePanz, and welcome! We have a stricter moderation than typical forums, and we are quite firm about sticking to our scope. We don't discuss anything about the possible benefits of eating a food, so I had to remove that part of the question, sorry. The other part - is it safe, does it change the taste, the color, etc. - is certainly on topic, so no change there, I even gave you an upvote for the nice question.

Comment: I would expect the tea to get more bitter as time pass; and cooler.

Comment: @rumtscho thanks for the notes & the upvote :) Next time i will be more careful!

Answer (score 4):

It might be worth trying coldbrew matcha for what you're trying to do. If you have a thermos already, try it at home over a weekend and see if it keeps well enough for your tastes. Matcha may settle if you leave it long enough, and many people enjoy the froth the most, so it really benefits from being made and drunk fresh.

Comment: I will try to make it like this too :) I was just thinking that is better to drink it warm!
I am new to the matcha tea culture and i'm discovering now the options that i have :)

Answer (score 3):

If the thermos is good, it will store very well through the day. I can only speak from my experience, but I prepare a thermos of matcha almost daily and it tastes nice by the end of the day. I have tried this with pure water + match and also with added milk (plant-based) and did not notice any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What i have noticed , however, is that its getting more braun as time pass. I mean, i prepare my thermos at 7:30 and at 13:00 it has lost its fresh green color ... thats what i have noticed.

Comment: This might depend on the brand of matcha powder used because I have never encountered such a color change. Usually, prepared in the morning it has the same color in the evening.

Comment: Interesting.... can you propose me some brand ? or even better the brand you use !!! Being new to the matcha tea world . i have to taste 3-4 brands to stay after. I hope its not against the rules of the site!

Comment: @LePanz it may just be that the matcha is settling. Try getting the wire balls from one of those blender bottles or something similar and just giving it a nice shake before you pour.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg believe i have test it too :) Knowing that matcha is powder it was my first thought! Thank you anyway :)